# why server return error code 502

Tags: java, url

This is my code for for reading file from [URL](http://dbpedia.org/data/Germany.json).

```
 URL url = new URL(urlString);
 reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

But the problem is-

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 502 for 
URL: http://dbpedia.org/data/Germany.json
```

This error does not occur every-time. can anybody help me?

Comment: The web-site you are currently trying to access is under maintenance at this time.
We are sorry for any inconvenience this has caused

Comment: but the link is perfectly working\

Comment: The link doesn't appear to work at the moment

Comment: Why did you tag "Java" to this question ? this is a server related issue. Server must be down or overloaded. Try after some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to access this link in the browser:

[image]

And according to [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) code **502** is:

> The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server.

So that's the answer. :-)

in the console

[image]

Comment: few min ago it was ok but now it is showiing this msg. thanks